# How can I navigate react native pages using stack screen headerLeft and headerRight?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am working on a react native project and I would like to customize the react stack navigator. The default "back button" of a stack navigator screen gives the name of the previous screen and a back arrow. I would like to change the name and more importantly remove the back button carrot.

I visited the React Native documentation and the answer seems to be using the **"headerLeft"** option, but I don't know how to navigate back to my previous screen. If I use `onPress={() => navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})}`

then I get an error saying `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: navigation`

So how I can I navigate my stack navigator using headerLeft and headerRight?

The piece of code giving the error is:

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ChoresOptionsPage"
        component={ChoresOptionsPage}
        options={{
          headerBackTitle: "Cancel",
          headerTitle: "Add Chores",
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})}
              title="Cancel"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
```

Here is my file code: -- App.js --

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#FFA06A"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerTitle: (props) => <Title></Title>,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ChoresOptionsPage"
        component={ChoresOptionsPage}
        options={{
          headerBackTitle: "Cancel",
          headerTitle: "Add Chores",
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})}
              title="Cancel"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
        
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ChoreLibrary"
        component={ChoreLibrary}
        options={{
          headerTitle: "Chore Library",
          headerBackTitle: "Cancel",
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
              title="Save"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
            <Stack.Screen
        name="CustomChore"
        component={CustomChore}
        options={{
          headerTitle: "Custom Chore",
          headerBackTitle: "Cancel",
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
              title="Save"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  )
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can pass a function that expects the *navigation* object, to the *options* prop, kind of what is done in [this example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component) from the docs.

So the result, for your piece of code, would be something like:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="ChoresOptionsPage"
  component={ChoresOptionsPage}
  options={({navigation}) => ({
    headerBackTitle: "Cancel",
    headerTitle: "Add Chores",
    headerLeft: () => (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})}
        title="Cancel"
        color="#fff"
      />
    ),
    })}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!! It did yield an error letting me know that I need to use "name" instead of "routeName"  [docs here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#navigate) but this was spot on.